# Handlebars If statement inside each loses context

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a Handlebars template, which is used inside EmberJS as a template for a certain Route. The Route provides a model like this:

```
{
    "Id": 50, 
    "UserId": 2, 
    "Name": "sdfq", 
    "UserFullName": "Bla bla", 
    "branches": [
            {"Id": 2, "Name": "Test branch23", "ProviderId": 50, "AvailabilityId": 1},
            {"Id": 3, "Name": "Branch nr 21", "ProviderId": 50, "AvailabilityId": null}
    ]
}
```

For this model I render a template like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered ">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="active">
                        <th>{{language 'Id'}}</th>
                        <th>{{language 'Name'}}</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {{#each branches}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{Id}}</td>
                    <td>{{Name}}</td>
                    <td>
                        {{#link-to 'branch.edit' ProviderId Id tagName='button' class='btn btn-primary' }}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit{{/link-to}}
                        {{#if AvailabilityId}}
                            {{#link-to 'availability.edit' AvailabilityId tagName='button' class='btn btn-primary' }}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Availability <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>{{/link-to}}
                        {{else}}
                            {{#link-to 'availability.add_for_branch' ../Id tagName='button' class='btn btn-success' }}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Availability <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>{{/link-to}}
                        {{/if}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}
            </table>
```

Everything renders fine for the first time and correct links are shown for correct rows. 
Now when I try to click a link `availability.edit` I get an error 
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AvailabilityId' of undefined
If i track down the error then it leads to nothing related to my code (an jQuery internal function).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AvailabilityId' of undefined ember-1.3.1.js:3936
ChainNodePrototype.unchain ember-1.3.1.js:3936
ChainNodePrototype.remove ember-1.3.1.js:3914
Ember.unwatchPath ember-1.3.1.js:4087
Ember.unwatch ember-1.3.1.js:4156
Ember.removeObserver ember-1.3.1.js:5406
(anonymous function) ember-1.3.1.js:23856
sendEvent ember-1.3.1.js:2351
Ember.Evented.Ember.Mixin.create.trigger ember-1.3.1.js:17629
Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend.trigger ember-1.3.1.js:21769
superWrapper ember-1.3.1.js:1230
ViewCollection.trigger ember-1.3.1.js:21834
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend._notifyWillDestroyElement ember-1.3.1.js:23348
Ember.merge.destroyElement ember-1.3.1.js:24337
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.destroyElement ember-1.3.1.js:23323
superWrapper ember-1.3.1.js:1230
Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend.destroy ember-1.3.1.js:21803
superWrapper ember-1.3.1.js:1230
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.destroy ember-1.3.1.js:23657
superWrapper ember-1.3.1.js:1230
(anonymous function) ember-1.3.1.js:24782
sendEvent ember-1.3.1.js:2351
notifyBeforeObservers ember-1.3.1.js:2723
propertyWillChange ember-1.3.1.js:2549
set ember-1.3.1.js:2815
Ember.trySet ember-1.3.1.js:2884
(anonymous function) ember-1.3.1.js:6894
tryable ember-1.3.1.js:2245
Ember.tryFinally ember-1.3.1.js:1412
suspendListener ember-1.3.1.js:2248
Ember._suspendObserver ember-1.3.1.js:5435
Binding._sync ember-1.3.1.js:6893
DeferredActionQueues.flush ember-1.3.1.js:5650
Backburner.end ember-1.3.1.js:5741
Backburner.run ember-1.3.1.js:5780
Ember.run ember-1.3.1.js:6181
Ember.EventDispatcher.Ember.Object.extend._bubbleEvent ember-1.3.1.js:21515
handleViewEvent ember-1.3.1.js:21459
Ember.handleErrors ember-1.3.1.js:899
(anonymous function) ember-1.3.1.js:21450
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.10.2.js:5095
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle jquery-1.10.2.js:4766
```

If i remove the if statement `{{#if AvailabilityId}}` and display two links all the time, they work fine.
I have tried modifying the scope by using:

```
{{#link-to 'availability.edit' ../AvailabilityId tagName='button' class='btn btn-primary' }}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Availability <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>{{/link-to}}
```

But it does not seem to have any little effect, even ../../ had no effect (Which leads all suspicions to the if block, which is probably causing the error).

Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

uppercase properties are generally considered global properties, if you're going to use them you should fully qualify them.  This is more than likely the problem you're running into

```
{{#each branch in branches}}
    <tr>
       <td>{{branch.Id}}</td>
       <td>{{branch.Name}}</td>
       <td>
         {{#link-to 'branch.edit' branch.ProviderId branch.Id tagName='button' class='btn btn-primary' }}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit{{/link-to}}
         {{#if branch.AvailabilityId}}
            {{#link-to 'availability.edit' branch.AvailabilityId tagName='button' class='btn btn-primary' }}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Availability <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>{{/link-to}}
         {{else}}
            {{#link-to 'availability.add_for_branch' branch.Id tagName='button' class='btn btn-success' }}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Availability <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>{{/link-to}}
         {{/if}}
       </td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the cause of the problem. When clicking on one of the links i still get the same error, seems like the "branch" is undefined after I click the link.

Comment: As a matter of fact, if i click one of the links (availability.edit OR availability.add_for_branch) TWO times, the first time it throws an error and second time it manages to change the url for the correct link, but does not render the template (Maybe the first click, which caused the error, made Ember think it had already rendered a new view and does not need to do it again or smt )

Comment: yeah, it looks like when it sets up the watch it ignores the scope, you're best bet is to drop down to lower case property names, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lidud/2/edit

Comment: Thanks, the problem was using Uppercased property names, after droppong to lowercase, all seems to work. I am going to mark this as appropriate answer.

Comment: I don't have words for this error. It is freaking me out. I don't want to lowercase my properties...

Comment: What version of Ember are you using, I believe they removed global lookups a few versions ago, which would have removed this problem.